# How can I make two HTML templates conditionally for one component with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular8, angular-ng-if

I have this component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
  providers: [YoutubeService]
})
```

For some reasons I need to create an other templateURL **form1.component.html** conditionally.

this component contains a dialog with two buttons ( *button1* and *button2* )
if i click *button1* i want form.component load **form.component.html** and if i click *button2* i want form.component load **form1.component.html**

How can I conditionally use 2 HTML files for one component?

is there a solution like this?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: if (condition) => './form.component.html' else './form1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
  providers: [YoutubeService]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app-component.html :

```
<first-component *ngIf="compoService.isfirst"></first-component>
<second-component *ngIf="!compoService.isfirst"></second-component>
```

app-component.ts :

```
import { CompoService } from '../compo.service';
//... other imports

//... logic

constructor(public compoService: CompoService) {}

//... logic
```

compo.service.ts :

```
export class CompoService {

  ServiceSubject = new Subject<any[]>();

  isfirst: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  template1() {
    this.isfirst = false;
  }

  template2() {
    this.isfirst = true;
  }
```

dialog-component.html :

```
<input type="radio" name="radio3" id="template1">     
 <label for="template1" (click)="template1()">load templae 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio3" id="template2">           
 <label for="template2" (click)="template2()">load templae 2</label>
```

dialog-component.ts :

```
import { CompoService } from '../compo.service';
//... other imports

//... logic

constructor(public compoService: CompoService) {}

  template1() {
    this.compoService.template1();
  }

  template2() {
    this.compoService.template2();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how angular components work.

You'll need to either use an `*ngIf` condition in your component's HTML, or you need to conditionally insert a sub-component into your component's template.

If you want to share logic between these sub-components, they can extend a base class:

```js
abstract class ComponentBase { }
class ChildComponentOne extends ComponentBase { }
class ChildComponentTwo extends ComponentBase { }
```